# Problem with Chromium Web Browser

Tags: 20.04, chromium

This problem occurs time to time.How to get rid of this ?
The refresh don't work. I can't go to the history pages to delete my data.The only way to solve this problem is to restart PC

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with further details of what research you have done and what happens when you click on reload. These references might also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475262/what-causes-a-sigtrap-in-a-debug-session and https://www.chromestory.com/2019/12/chrome-crash-page-error-codes/ Is this an issue you should take up with the developers?

Comment: I do not see what this has to do with Ubuntu it is a problem with the browser.